# How to debug corruption in the managed heap

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, windbg, heap-corruption

My program throws an error which it cannot handle by a `catch(Exception e)` block and then it crashes:

> Access Violation Corrupted State Exception.

This is the weird thing, because, as I know, corrupted state exceptions are thrown from unmanaged code, while here I get this exception while calling a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) method.

The code runs in a background thread and crashes from time to time which cannot be easily reproduced. So I attached [WinDbg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDbg) to the process and have the following stack of the exception:

```
000000001dabd8c8 000007feea129a1d [HelperMethodFrame: 000000001dabd8c8]
000000001dabda00 000007fee90cfce8 System.Text.StringBuilder.ExpandByABlock(Int32)
000000001dabda40 000007fee90cfba4 System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(Char*, Int32)
000000001dabdaa0 000007fee9102955 System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(System.String, Int32, Int32)
000000001dabdaf0 000007ff00bf5ce3 MineUtils.Common.Strings.Strings.Replace(System.String, System.String, System.String, Boolean, Boolean)
000000001dabdb90 000007ff00bf5a59 MineUtils.Common.Strings.Strings.RemoveSubstrings(System.String, System.String, System.String, Boolean) [D:\Programs\Visual Studio 2005 Projects\MineUtils.Common\Strings\Strings.Common-Main.cs @ 1481
```

WinDbg shows this exception occurred:

```
EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffffffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 000007feea129a1d (clr!WKS::gc_heap::find_first_object+0x0000000000000092)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[1]: 0000000000003d80
Attempt to read from address 0000000000003d80
```

I read such exceptions can be handled with a method attribute [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions], but why does this exception ever occur if I only use StringBuilder?

This is the previous WinDbg analysis (`StringBuilder.ToString()` causes the exception):

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

FAULTING_IP:
clr!WKS::gc_heap::find_first_object+92
000007fe`ea129a1d f70100000080    test    dword ptr [rcx],80000000h

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffffffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 000007feea129a1d (clr!WKS::gc_heap::find_first_object+0x0000000000000092)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000001
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[1]: 0000000000001c98
Attempt to read from address 0000000000001c98

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000000

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  0000000000001c98

READ_ADDRESS:  0000000000001c98

FOLLOWUP_IP:
clr!WKS::gc_heap::find_first_object+92
000007fe`ea129a1d f70100000080    test    dword ptr [rcx],80000000h

MOD_LIST: <ANALYSIS/>

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

MANAGED_STACK:
(TransitionMU)
000000001AB7DFC0 000007FEE90CFE07 mscorlib_ni!System.Text.StringBuilder.ToString()+0x27
000000001AB7E010 000007FF00C750A9 SgmlReaderDll!Sgml.Entity.ScanToken(System.Text.StringBuilder, System.String, Boolean)+0x169
000000001AB7E080 000007FF00C760E6 SgmlReaderDll!Sgml.SgmlDtd.ParseParameterEntity(System.String)+0xc6
000000001AB7E0F0 000007FF00C76FD8 SgmlReaderDll!Sgml.SgmlDtd.ParseModel(Char, Sgml.ContentModel)+0x298
000000001AB7E160 000007FF00C7701C SgmlReaderDll!Sgml.SgmlDtd.ParseModel(Char, Sgml.ContentModel)+0x2dc
000000001AB7E1D0 000007FF00C7701C SgmlReaderDll!Sgml.SgmlDtd.ParseModel(Char, Sgml.ContentModel)+0x2dc
000000001AB7E240 000007FF00C76BA5 SgmlReaderDll!Sgml.SgmlDtd.ParseContentModel(Char)+0x65
000000001AB7E290 000007FF00C763D7 SgmlReaderDll!Sgml.SgmlDtd.ParseElementDecl()+0xe7
000000001AB7E320 000007FF00C747A1 SgmlReaderDll!Sgml.SgmlDtd.Parse()+0xc1
000000001AB7E370 000007FF00C73EF5 SgmlReaderDll!Sgml.SgmlDtd.Parse(System.Uri, System.String, System.IO.TextReader, System.String, System.String, System.Xml.XmlNameTable)+0x175
000000001AB7E410 000007FF00C73B33 SgmlReaderDll!Sgml.SgmlReader.LazyLoadDtd(System.Uri)+0x163
000000001AB7E480 000007FF00C737B9 SgmlReaderDll!Sgml.SgmlReader.OpenInput()+0x19
000000001AB7E4E0 000007FF00C7334C SgmlReaderDll!Sgml.SgmlReader.Read()+0x1c
000000001AB7E530 000007FEE5983C4C System_Xml_ni!System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(System.Xml.XmlDocument, System.Xml.XmlReader, Boolean)+0xac
000000001AB7E590 000007FEE5983730 System_Xml_ni!System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(System.Xml.XmlReader)+0x90
...
000000001AB7F0A0 000007FEE97ED792 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()+0x82
000000001AB7F100 000007FEE90A181C mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)+0xdc
000000001AB7F160 000007FEE97E7F95 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)+0x1b5
000000001AB7F1E0 000007FEE97E7D90 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean)+0xb0
000000001AB7F220 000007FEE90EBA83 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()+0x193
000000001AB7F2C0 000007FEE90EB8D5 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()+0x35
(TransitionUM)

EXCEPTION_OBJECT: !pe 2a61228
Exception object: 0000000002a61228
Exception type:   System.ExecutionEngineException
Message:          <none>
InnerException:   <none>
StackTrace (generated):
<none>
StackTraceString: <none>
HResult: 80131506

MANAGED_OBJECT_NAME:  System.ExecutionEngineException

MANAGED_STACK_COMMAND:  _EFN_StackTrace

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 000007feea12bce4 to 000007feea129a1d

ADDITIONAL_DEBUG_TEXT:  Followup set based on attribute [Is_ChosenCrashFollowupThread] from Frame:[0] on thread:[PSEUDO_THREAD]

FAULTING_THREAD:  ffffffffffffffff

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  INVALID_POINTER_READ_CALL

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  INVALID_POINTER_READ_CALL

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_INVALID_POINTER_READ_WRONG_SYMBOLS_CALL__SYSTEM.EXECUTIONENGINEEXCEPTION
```

**UPDATED AGAIN**

Here is the WinDbg stack of the exception after I enabled [paged heap](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286470):

```
 (1480.e84): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
ntdll!ZwTerminateProcess+0xa:
00000000`77c415da c3              ret
0:023> !clrstack
OS Thread Id: 0xe84 (23)
Child SP         IP               Call Site
0000000037ded848 0000000077c415da [HelperMethodFrame: 0000000037ded848]
0000000037dedab0 000007fee9effd17 System.Text.StringBuilder.ToString()*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\mscorlib\8f7f691aa155c11216387cf3420d9d1b\mscorlib.ni.dll

0000000037dedb00 000007ff00cceae9 Sgml.Entity.ScanToken(System.Text.StringBuilder, System.String, Boolean)

0000000037dedb70 000007ff00cd19b2 Sgml.SgmlDtd.ParseAttDefault(Char, Sgml.AttDef)
0000000037dedbc0 000007ff00cd120b Sgml.SgmlDtd.ParseAttDef(Char)
0000000037dedc00 000007ff00cd1057 Sgml.SgmlDtd.ParseAttList(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<System.String,Sgml.AttDef>, Char)
0000000037dedc50 000007ff00cd10cd Sgml.SgmlDtd.ParseAttList(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<System.String,Sgml.AttDef>, Char)
0000000037dedca0 000007ff00cd0e9a Sgml.SgmlDtd.ParseAttList()
0000000037dedd10 000007ff00cce1f1 Sgml.SgmlDtd.Parse()
0000000037dedd60 000007ff00ccd945 Sgml.SgmlDtd.Parse(System.Uri, System.String, System.IO.TextReader, System.String, System.String, System.Xml.XmlNameTable)
0000000037dede00 000007ff00ccd582 Sgml.SgmlReader.LazyLoadDtd(System.Uri)
0000000037dede70 000007ff00ccd1f9 Sgml.SgmlReader.OpenInput()
0000000037deded0 000007ff00cccd8c Sgml.SgmlReader.Read()
0000000037dedf20 000007fee67b3bfc System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(System.Xml.XmlDocument, System.Xml.XmlReader, Boolean)*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Xml\8e4323f5bfb90be4621456033d8b404b\System.Xml.ni.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Xml\8e4323f5bfb90be4621456033d8b404b\System.Xml.ni.dll

0000000037dedf80 000007fee67b36e0 System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(System.Xml.XmlReader)
[deleted]
0000000037deea90 000007feea61d432 System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
0000000037deeaf0 000007fee9ed17ec System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
0000000037deeb50 000007feea617c35 System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
0000000037deebd0 000007feea617a30 System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean)
0000000037deec10 000007fee9f1b953 System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
0000000037deecb0 000007fee9f1b7a5 System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
0000000037def310 000007feeae4dc54 [DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame: 0000000037def310]
0:023> !verifyheap
-verify will only produce output if there are errors in the heap
The garbage collector data structures are not in a valid state for traversal.
It is either in the "plan phase," where objects are being moved around, or
we are at the initialization or shutdown of the gc heap. Commands related to
displaying, finding or traversing objects as well as gc heap segments may not
work properly. !dumpheap and !verifyheap may incorrectly complain of heap
consistency errors.
object 000000000e34caf8: bad member 000000001024b9a0 at 000000000e34cb08
curr_object:      000000000e34caf8
Last good object: 000000000e34cab0
----------------
0:023> !analyze
Last event: 1480.e84: Exit process 0:1480, code 80131506
  debugger time: Sun Sep 18 14:22:42.592 2011 (UTC + 1:00)
0:023> !analyze -v
Last event: 1480.e84: Exit process 0:1480, code 80131506
  debugger time: Sun Sep 18 14:22:42.592 2011 (UTC + 1:00)
0:023> .do e34cab0
          ^ Syntax error in '.do e34cab0'
0:023> !do e34cab0
Name:        System.String
MethodTable: 000007feea026870
EEClass:     000007fee9baed58
Size:        72(0x48) bytes
File:        C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll
String:      appliedFiltersContainer
Fields:
              MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr            Value Name
000007feea02c758  4000103        8         System.Int32  1 instance               23 m_stringLength
000007feea02b298  4000104        c          System.Char  1 instance               61 m_firstChar
000007feea026870  4000105       10        System.String  0   shared           static Empty
                                 >> Domain:Value  00000000021343a0:000000000db21420 <<
0:023> !do e34caf8
<Note: this object has an invalid CLASS field>
Name:        System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly
MethodTable: 000007feea02a128
EEClass:     000007fee9baf968
Size:        48(0x30) bytes
File:        C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll
Fields:
              MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr            Value Name
000007feea9ef7f0  4000e14        8 ...solveEventHandler  0 instance 0000000000000000 _ModuleResolve
000007feea036338  4000e15       10 ...che.InternalCache  0 instance 000000001024b9a0 m_cachedData
000007feea0259c8  4000e16       18        System.Object  0 instance 000000000e3abd18 m_syncRoot
000007feea033450  4000e17       20        System.IntPtr  1 instance         37a95f10 m_assembly
```

What can it be?

Comment: You shouldn't be able to get that sort of exception, but you haven't shown us your code. You need to post the `Replace` function and maybe `RemoveSubstring`.

Comment: Probably I have a wrong interpretation of the WinDbg results, but CLR stack points to these methods, I have posted their source.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. Does it always crash in that method, or did you only see it crash there once?

Comment: The program parses web pages and crashes in different places since works with numerous threads, but always a StringBuilder is there at the top of the stack. Last time there was StringBuilder.ToString() method which caused the same exception, now it is StringBuilder.Append().

Comment: It's actually the garbage collector that's on the top of the stack. The StringBuilder is there because that's what triggers the GC. As noted below, your problem is heap corruption which is not generally caused by the code that actually crashes.

Comment: If your code does not call unmanaged code itself, you can check at DevExpress support knowledge base, they do call unmanaged code and could have a bug.

Comment: This looks very much like your unmanaged code wasn't developed to run in a multi-threaded environment. I suggest you encapuslate all calls to the unmanaged code in `lock {}` blocks, so that only one thread at a time can access it. This still may not be enough, as the code may require that only a single thread, _ever_ should access it.

Comment: Net_prog, did you ever manage to find the root cause? I know it's years ago, but maybe you remember?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Recently, I was faced with a managed heap corruption which was something new to me. I was very frustrated with it and had to learn many things to be able to debug it. I want to thank Seva Titov who gave me right direction to start. His answer was concise and very helpful. I want to log the actions I have taken to debug the problem for my own reference. Probably this will be helpful for others who are new to this.

**Debug Heap Corruption in .NET 4:**

**How to suspect the heap corruption?**

Briefly:

1. The application crashes randomly with no regards to the applied exception catching and even goes through blankets like `catch(Exception)` which are supposed to catch all exceptions.
2. Examining the CLR stack in the application crash dumps shows the garbage collector on the top of the stack:

   ```
   000000001dabd8c8 000007feea129a1d [**HelperMethodFrame**: 000000001dabd8c8]
   000000001dabda00 000007fee90cfce8 System.Text.StringBuilder.ExpandByABlock(Int32)
   000000001dabda40 000007fee90cfba4 System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(Char*, Int32)
   ...

   EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffffffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
   ExceptionAddress: 000007feea129a1d (**clr!WKS::gc_heap**::find_first_object+0x0000000000000092)
      ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
     ExceptionFlags: 00000000
   NumberParameters: 2
      Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
      Parameter[1]: 0000000000003d80
   ...
   ```
3. The CLR stack always shows different points. Whether the crash occurred or the code which is shown is clearly irrelevant, like StringBuilder's method which is shown to cause the exception.

*For more details refer to *[.NET Crash: Managed Heap Corruption calling unmanaged code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/02/09/528591.aspx%5D%28http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/02/09/528591.aspx)**.

**Going step by step. Each next step is used if the previous one doesn't help.**

**Step 1. Check the code.**

Check the code for unsafe or native code usages:

1. Review the code for `unsafe`, `DllImport` statements.
2. Download [.NET Reflector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector) and use it to analyze the application assemblies for `PInvoke`. In the same way, analyze the third-party assemblies which are used by the application.

If unsafe or native code usage is found, direct extra attention to those. The most common cause of the heap corruption in such cases is a buffer overflow or an argument type mismatch. Ensure that the buffer supplied to the native code to fill is big enough and that all arguments passed to the native code are of the expected type.

**Step 2. Check if this *corrupted state exception* can be caught.**

To handle such exceptions, one need to decorate the method which contains the `catch(Exception)` statement with the `[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]` attribute or apply the following in the `app.config` file:

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy enabled="true" />
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

In the case the exception was caught successfully, you can log and examine it. This means this is not a corrupted heap issue.

Corrupted heap exceptions cannot be handled at all: *[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions doesn't seem to work](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/18fb14cb-33be-4af7-9bf1-dc651cdf1239/)*.

More information on corrupted state exceptions, see *[All about Corrupted State Exceptions in .NET4](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/net/All-about-Corrupted-State-Exceptions-in-NET4.aspx)*.

**Step 3. Live debugging.**

In this step, we debug the crashing application live in the production environment (or where we can reproduce the crash).

Download *Debugging Tools for Windows* from *[Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8279)* (a web installer will be downloaded which will allow selecting the required components to install - mark all components). It will install both 32 and 64 bit (if your system is x64) versions of the required debugging tools.

Here one needs to know how to attach WinDbg to a live process, how to take crash dumps and examine them, how to load [SOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDbg#SOS) extension in WinDbg (google for details).

Enable debugging helpers:

1. Launch Application Verifier (`C:\Program Files\Application Verifier` - use the required edition, either x86 or x64, depending on your executable compilation mode), add your executable there in the left pane and in the right pane check one node "Basics / Heaps". Save the changes.
2. Launch Global Flags helper (`C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows\gflags.exe` - again select the correct edition, x86 or x64). Once *Global Flags* is started, go to the "Image File" tab and at the top text box enter the name of your executable file without any paths (for example, "MyProgram.exe"). Then press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key and set the following boxes:

   - Enable heap tail checking
   - Enable heap free checking
   - Enable heap parameter checking
   - Enable heap validation on call
   - Disable heap coalesce on free
   - Enable page heap
   - Enable heap tagging
   - Enable application verifier
   - Debugger (type the path to the installed WinDbg in the text box to the right, for example, `C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x64)\windbg.exe -g`).

   For more details, refer to *[Heap Corruption, Part 2](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/configuration/heap-corruption-part-2)*.
3. Go to "Control Panel/System and Security/System" (or right-click "Computer" in the Start menu and select "Properties". There click "Advanced system settings", in the displayed dialog, go to "Advanced" tab and click the "Environment Variables" button. In the displayed dialog, add a new System variable (if you are an system administrator - a User variable otherwise - you need need to logout/login in this case). The required variable is "COMPLUS_HeapVerify" with a value of "1". More details can be found in Stack Overflow question *[.NET/C#: How to set debugging environment variable COMPLUS_HeapVerify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469225/net-c-how-to-set-debugging-environment-variable-complus-heapverify)*.

Now we are ready to start debugging. Start the application. WinDbg should start automatically for it. Leave the application running until it crashes into WinDgb and then examine the dump.

**TIP**: To quickly remove *Global Flags*, *Application Verifier* and the debugger attachment settings, delete the following key in the registry:
x64 - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\*YourAppName*`

**Step 4. Enable MDAs.**

Try to use the Managed Debugging Assistants. Details are in Stack Overflow question *[What MDAs are useful to track a heap corruption?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559374/net-c-what-mdas-are-useful-to-track-a-heap-corruption)*.

MDAs must be used along with WinDbg. I used them even along with *Global Flags* and *Application Verifier*.

**Step 5. Enable GCStress.**

Using GCStress is an extreme option, because the application becomes almost unusable, but it is still a way to go. More details are in *[GCStress: How to turn on in Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556224/gcstress-how-to-turn-on-in-win-7)*.

**Step 6. Compile for x86.**

If your application is currently being compiled for "Any CPU" or "x64" platform, try to compile it for "x86" if there is no difference for you which platform to use. I saw this reported to solve the problem for somebody.

**Step 7. Disable concurrent GC - this is what worked for me**

There is a reported known issue in .NET 4 reported in the thread *[Access Violation in .NET 4 Runtime in gc_heap::garbage_collect with no unmanaged modules](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/33920b39-690c-42c8-b04a-0f1f7176835a/)*. The problem can be solved by disabling the concurrent GC in the `app.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <gcConcurrent enabled="false" />
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 11):

You have managed heap corruption. It is not easy to find the root cause of the problem for managed heap corruption, because the problem usually demonstrates itself long after the heap is corrupted. In your case, the `StringBuilder` is a red herring. Corruption happened sometime before.

What I would do is the following:

1. Check if you have any unsafe C# code. If you have any, double check the logic there.
2. Enable [paged heap](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286470) for your application. Running it with paged heap will help uncover problems with unmanaged code -- in case unmanaged code is corrupting the managed heap.
3. Run `!VerifyHeap` in different places. This way you might be able to localize the place in your code where corruption happens.
4. If you have the server type of garbage collection enabled for your application, temporarily change that to workstation garbage collection -- you will get more predictable behavior this way.
5. Read through Tesses' blog post *[.NET Crash: Managed Heap Corruption calling unmanaged code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/02/09/net-crash-managed-heap-corruption-calling-unmanaged-code.aspx)*. It demonstrates some examples of managed heap corruption.

Note that when you will be running your code under WinDbg, you will come across occasional first chance AV. It is safe to ingore that, just type `sxd av` once you attach WinDbg to the process, and investigate only second chance AVs.

Comment: I have another crash stack after enabled paged heap, now it points to another code, could you please take a look. !VerifyHeap didn't give anything this time.

Comment: @net_prog, was this a second chance AV this time? You only need to look at second chance AVs for the heap corruption. If !VerifyHeap does not report any corruption, this means the heap is still fine, and you are hitting some other issue, not a heap corruption.

Comment: I suppose it was a first chance: "(f24.103c): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)" and I didn't continue to see whether the program would exit, I just stopped the debugging. I will have to wait for another crash for details.

Comment: I enabled workstation GC and it seemed to work fine for more than a week, than I removed that workstation GC and got another crash, I have updated the first post, it was a first chance exception which lead to program termination and the heap had errors as written in the post update. Unfortunately Pageheap didn't show the actual cause of the problem, again points to StringBuilder. What can I do else?

Comment: How it should look when Pageheap causes the exception? Is it always a second chance exception? Does it have a program termination statement after the exception? In my last case this was a first chance exception which lead to program termination and Pageheap was enabled, what could that mean?

Comment: In most cases that I came accross pageheap always caused second chance AV. However I could easily imagine it might not get to the second change AV. This would happen if: a) there is explicit `catch (...)` handler for all exceptions; and b) application thinks it is much smarter than OS and it swallows exceptions it is not supposed to. In well written applications if you don't know how to recover from exception, you should pass it on to OS (and debugger, if attached).

Comment: Yes, I catch all exceptions in the background threads in order to log them. However this heap corruption exception prevents the catching code from execution. Does such "swallowing" break my efforts in catching the problem cause? Even with PageHeap it points to StringBuilder. I just checked and that code doesn't use any unsafe portions (I mean SGMLReader).

Comment: So, logically - this time I had a first time (because of swallowing) exception which terminated my program and that exception was critical (not catchable by managed code). Would this be a PageHeap exception, it would not point to StringBuilder which is a "red herring". So PageHeap didn't cause the exception (while I see the heap is not correct as per my update above), this means that something else happens or there are problems with my Pageheap settings... I really need a kick to the right direction.

Comment: I would start with figuring out who called into TerminateProcess. Check usage of your try/catch blocks for possible blanket `catch (Exception)`. It's ok if you do blanket catch, but make sure you re-throw the exception. For unmanaged code (if you have any) don't use `catch (...)`.

Comment: Very interesting, please take a look at the last answer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/33920b39-690c-42c8-b04a-0f1f7176835a/). Is this something related to my case?

Comment: It _might_ be the same. The behavior is similar, but you cannot tell unless you know what caused the issue in the article you found and are able to confirm that the same issue corrupts GC heap in your case. The similarity of call stack in this case does not matter, because it is happening long after the corruption.

Comment: In my case PageHeap doesn't help (doesn't fire at all), same as AppVerifier, same as COMPLUS_HeapVerify flag. This corruption is very weird considering I don't have unmanaged code. At the same time the last crash clearly shows a heap problem with the command `!verifyheap` (the last good object is shown to be FreeObject - how that happens and why - no idea). I already posted several questions here trying to understand how *managed* code can corrupt the heap.